# Enable Grizzly to perform JaaS simple HTTP AUTH

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jaas, grizzly

How can I make Grizzly HTTP server allow JaaS for simple HTTP AUTH?
I can't see any code/sample out there: There's another post here in StackOverflow that directly assumes that jaaS is available in Grizzly, but doesn't explain how to add it.

Comment: Have you succeeded putting up Auth? I'm looking for some Samples and How-Tos, too. Wintermute's answer helped, but everywhere it is only described how to do it using Servlets. I'm running standalone... (GrizzlyServerFactory.create()) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the Grizzly HTTP server provides basic auth 'out of the box'. If you do not want to use a full-blown implementation like glassfish, you can implement your own filter and add it to the list of grizzly filters. Here is an example of how to  extract the login data via HTTP basic auth and how to integrate it in JAAS objects within the grizzly context. But it requires a significant amount of coding.

http://java.net/projects/jersey/sources/svn/content/trunk/jersey/samples/https-clientserver-grizzly/src/main/java/com/sun/jersey/samples/https_grizzly/auth/SecurityFilter.java?rev=5160

Hope that helps.